# Should a bounty question be closed?

Tags: discussion

I was reviewing a question that has a bounty tied to to it.  A couple people made valid points, but the author answers his own question.  My issue with this is, the author states the issue was with a workflow action which is part of a codeplex project, not native SharePoint workflow actions which the other answers were assuming.

Is this something that should be closed?  The initial question seemed valid, but the response and answer leads me to believe it's violating the third party stipulations or could be deemed too narrow.

[Post in reference](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/18307/sharepoint-2010-workflow-update-lookup-field-on-item).  Thoughts?

Comment: +1 Good question... It *does* have an answer so maybe it is worth keeping. I'll wait and see what other people think.

Comment: Regarding the bounty, it's currently still active. If the OP awards it to themselves they receive no reputation, effectively throwing the points away. However it is still possible for someone else to "win" it, according to the [rules](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work). Probably unlikely in this case though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Our [FAQ](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/faq#questions) currently states (emphasis mine):

> We don't accept questions about **commercial** products that integrate with, run on top of, or extend the SharePoint platform.

So questions that refer to open source or community style projects are allowed and therefore on that basis the question should stay open.

However I'd say it's unfortunate that the OP either didn't realise they were using something non-standard or neglected to mention it. In this case the best thing to do is edit the question to add this missing information and leave a comment for them to provide all information next time.